# [object][object] of type object ngFor error in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Working on Angular and getting the error. please check the code and suggest.
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object `[object Object]` of type 'object'. `NgFor` only supports binding to `Iterables` such as `Arrays`.

```
'''
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FirstService } from '../first.service';
    
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    
    import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    export interface faker {
      id? : number ;
      userId? : number;
      title? : string;
      completed? : boolean;
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-autocomplete',
      templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css']
    })
    export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
      questionlist : faker[] ;
      myFormControl = new FormControl()
    
      constructor(
        private fservice : FirstService
      ) { }
    
    formControl = new FormControl();
      autoFilter: Observable<faker[]>;
    
      ngOnInit(): void { 
      
        this.fservice.getall().subscribe( 
          res => { this.questionlist = <faker[]>res;
          });
    
        this.autoFilter = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(value => this.mat_filter(value))
        );    
      }
    
      private mat_filter(value: string): faker[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
        return this.questionlist.filter(option => option.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(option.title.toLowerCase()) === 0)
      }  
      
    }
'''
```

And the HTML FILE:

```
'''
    <mat-form-field style="width: 300px; margin: 50px auto; display: block;">
    
        <input type="text" placeholder="-------" matInput [formControl]="formControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of autoFilter" [value]="item.title">
            {{item.title}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      
    </mat-form-field>
'''
```

Note: `{{item.title}}` and `{{item}} [value]=item.title` and `[value]=item`. I have already tried. Please suggest why I am getting this error

The error message is:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. `NgFor` only supports binding to `Iterables` such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `autoFilter` is `Observable<faker[]>;` and you can't iterate `Observable`. So you may need to use `questionlist` that is an array of `faker`:

```
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of questionlist" [value]="item.title">
         {{item.title}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing an **object** to *ngFor

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages stated, `ngFor` only supports Iterables such as `Array`, so you cannot use it for `Object`. May be you are trying to iterate `autoFilter` as an `Object` instead of an `Array`. So make sure `autoFilter` is an `Array`.